# How can I stop scatter chart from autoscaling when data set changes in Plotly.js?

Tags: charts, plotly.js

I posted this question over at the Plotly community forum here: https://community.plotly.com/t/how-can-i-stop-scatter-chart-from-autoscaling-when-data-set-changes/78710. I'm posting here in order to increase the number of responses.

I'm wondering if there's a way to get Plotly.js to stop autoscaling the chart when the data changes.

For example, I have a scatter chart that looks like this:

[image]

I select the points at the bottom like this:

[image]

I hit delete to remove those point, but rather than show an empty region where the selection was, it seems to adjust the scale so that the remaining points fill the space:

[image]

I would like to stop that behavior if possible. Does anyone know how I can do that?